# Problem deploy Express.js to Vercel 500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Tags: express, deployment, vercel

when I want to deploy my Express.js to Vercel I get error 500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
but when I run on localhost everything goes fine, but now I get the following error when deploying to Vercel can anyone help me?

[image]

That's an error from my website page

this is my project folder structure
[image]

and this is the code from vercel.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    { "handle": "filesystem" },
    {
      "src": "routes/(.*)",
      "dest": "routes/$1"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/index.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is my package.json code

```
{
  "name": "Backend-API",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Backend-API-Express",
  "main": "./index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "excel4node": "^1.8.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.2",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "helmet": "^6.0.1",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.1.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.14",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.27.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.5.2",
    "webpack": "^5.90.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

someone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[from the docs](https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel):

> ### Standalone Express
>
> You can also create a standalone Express.js app with Vercel. First,
> create a file index.js and add it to an /api folder. This is similar
> to the app.js file in serverful Express.js applications. The /api
> directory is where we'll add our Serverless Functions.

and you do not need this in express app

```
 app.use(express.static('public'))
```

place static assets in the next.js' public folder

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error happens when you try to run a server instead of static content. The Vercel platform is made for static sites and Serverless Functions.

https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel